# Just upload to Jcenter and can't import to gradle

Tags: plugins, gradle, jcenter

I used [Gradle plugin dev](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-plugindev-plugin/blob/master/README.md) to upload my plugin to [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter). But now I do not know how to use it in gradle.

It fail finding the classpath. I build it like this:

> groupId:artifactId:version

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.fuzz.skeleton:app:1.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
}
```

My project can be found [here](https://bintray.com/fuzz-productions/gradle-plugins/skeleton/1.0.0.RELEASE/view#).

Comment: It Can you give the link to Bintray package? Is the package linked to JCenter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to request that your package be included in JCenter. Specifically, you have not accomplished step 3 of [this process](http://plugins.gradle.org/submit). Additionally, you'll want to request inclusion in the [Gradle plugins repository](https://bintray.com/gradle/gradle-plugins) so that your plugin will be available on the [Gradle plugin portal](http://plugins.gradle.org/).